# I have this error : raise Teminator turtle.Terminator

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Other people asked this question but it didn't help me.
I wrote this code:

```
import turtle
import time

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

t.pd()
t.pensize(3)
t.speed(10)
t.circle(100)

time.sleep(2)
turtle.bye()

fq = str(input("What shape is it? - "))
fq = fq.lower()
while fq != "circle":
    print("It's not the right shape")
    fq = str(input("What shape is it? - "))
    fq = fq.lower()
print("Good Job!")

s = turtle.Screen()
h = turtle.Turtle()

t.pd()
t.pensize(3)
t.speed(10)

t.goto(50, 0)
t.goto(50, 50)
t.goto(0, 50)
t.goto(0, 0)

time.sleep(2)
s.bye()

sq = str(input("What shape is it? - "))
sq = sq.lower()
while sq != "square":
    print("It's not the right shape")
    sq = str(input("What shape is it? - "))
    sq = sq.lower()
print("Good Job!")
```

and I get this problem when I get to the second turtle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/סער 07.סער/Desktop/Python/Shapes.py", line 24, in <module>
    h = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C:\Users\סער 07.סער\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "C:\Users\סער 07.סער\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\סער 07.סער\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\סער 07.סער\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\סער 07.סער\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Why do I have this kind of problem?
The first turtle is fine without problems
but when it gets to the second, I get the above error.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but what is the purpose of the second turtle?  It's never used.  All of the following draw and goto commands still use the first turtle object.

Comment: what do i need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You continue to use turtle after you twice terminate turtle with `bye()`:

```
turtle.bye()
s.bye()
```

What did you expect to happen?  To setup for the next question, you can use commands like `screen.reset()`, `screen.clear()`, `turtle.reset()`, or simply `turtle.clear()`:

```
from turtle import Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.pensize(3)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-100)  # center circle on screen
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(100)

fq = input("What shape is this? - ").lower()

while fq != 'circle':
    print("That's not the right shape.")
    fq = input("What shape is this? - ").lower()

print("Good Job!")

turtle.clear()

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-25, -25)  # center square on screen
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(90)

sq = input("What shape is it? - ").lower()

while sq != 'square':
    print("That's not the right shape.")
    sq = input("What shape is it? - ").lower()

print("Good Job!")
```